# dynamically added Facebook send button not rendering

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to add a Facebook send button (which is not yet supported with iframes) dynamically to the page after it loads (due to the way the site is constructed, it will be part of an HTML template loaded through AJAX on a user action).

Though I'm importing the FB JavaScript SDK, when I load the new content through AJAX, the marked element is not "transformed" into the FB send button.

I've tried:

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="example.com"></div>
```

and

```
<fb:send href="example.com"></fb:send>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried loading the sdk after the ajax call has been made?

Comment: Thanks... I guess I was hoping I wouldn't have to call FB.init every time, but it makes a lot of sense now to parse/process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you add an FBML element to the dom you should call

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: That documentation, at the time of this comment, does not list fb:send as a supported tag.