# How to insert iFrame/PHP with ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I am trying to include a Facebook like button iFrame that has PHP in it:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&send=false&layout=button_count" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 115px; height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

when the site loads this, it displays as in a list:

```
   <ul class="recent-list">
        <?php 
            require("inc/connect.php");
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 20", $link);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   ?>

            <li id="qoute-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"  class="quote-wrap group">
                <span>

                            <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&send=false&layout=button_count" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 115px; height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

                </span>

                <div class="quote">

                    <p>
                    <?php echo htmlentities($row['quote']); ?>
                    </p>

                </div><!-- /.quote -->
            </li>

                <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

But when someone click a button that fetches more list-items, the iFrame should be included...

```
function getQuotes(start, limit) {
                //Clear the recent list element
                //$(".recent-list").html("");
                var  recent = $(".recent-list");

               $(".recent-list li").animate({opacity: 0.1} , 800).hide(500);

                $.ajax({

                  url: "quotes.php?start=" + start + "&limit=" + limit,
                  success: function (data) {
                    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
                    console.log("success");
                    //Data should now be a javascript array of objects.
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                      var newElem = jQuery("<li></li>").attr('id', data[i].id).addClass('quote-wrap-group');
                      newElem.append("<div class='quote'><p>" + data[i].quote + "</p></div>");
                      $(".recent-list").append(newElem);
                    }
                  }
                });
              }
                 var currentIndex = 0;  
                   $("#more").click(function () {

                     getQuotes(currentIndex, 20);
                     currentIndex += 10;
                   });
```

When I try to include the iframe in the js above, nothing happens. No error, nothing is returned...

quotes.php:

```
$start = $_GET['start'];
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit;
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die("Error in query: ".mysql_error());

    $data = array(); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }

    echo(json_encode($data));
```

live version. Click "Get more". The quotes appear, but no like button.

http://kdevs.site40.net/#more

Comment: In the live example, you don't add iframe tags. It would work normally if you had been added.

Comment: Yes I did, when the page loads. But when clicking "Get more quotes", it doesn't appear. When I inserted the iFrames or attempted too, the ajax broke.

Comment: do you really need to use iframes? if you're ok with FBML (and hopefully you are), you could check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926145/dynamically-added-facebook-send-button-not-rendering

Comment: I mean, in the current code the function that runs when user clicks on the button (getQuotes) does not add iframe tags. Are you sure you don't forget sth?

Comment: I tried adding it to getQuotes, but it breaks.

Comment: We prefer seeing the error message rather than "it breaks".

Comment: There isn't an error message, but when trying to add thee iframe to newElem, it stops the PHP/ajax from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't add the iframe tags while building the `<li>` it the success function

all you did was adding (for each row):

```
<li id="54" class="quote-wrap-group">
    <div class="quote">
         <p>fdggfdgdgdgfdg</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

a better approach will be to make the whole list items on server side, and echo it, and then append the html that you received in the *success* to the existing list

for example:

your php will look like this:

```
$data = getData();//Get the data from the database here;
foreach($data as $row): 
?>
   <li id="qoute-<?php echo $row["id"];?>" class="quote-wrap group">
       <span>
           <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo row["id"];?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 115px; height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
      </span>
      <div class="quote"><p><?php echo $row["quote"];?></p></div>
   </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

your javascript function will be:

```
function getQuotes(start, limit){
    $.ajax({
      url:"quotes.php?start=" + start + "&limit=" + limit,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(response){
         $("ul.recent-list").append(response);
      }
   });
}
```

this of course trying to show the principle, and not necessarily be the exact code you need to write. You need to add the other functionality (like hiding the previous quotes etc...)

Comment: `getQuotes` hides the current `li` and append new ones to the list. I think you're looking at the ones that has just been hidden.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz tnx for your attention, changed my answer to fit

Comment: Would I add this in quotes.php?

Comment: It depends on you, you can add it the `quotes.php` or create a new file and change the `url` parameter in the `$.ajax` call